# How to extract Hour Year and Month?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT DATEPART(year, (select convert (nvarchar(20),[DateFacture]) FROM [ArcoCerame].[dbo].[FactureClient]))  
    ,DATEPART(month, (select convert (nvarchar(20),[DateFacture]) FROM [ArcoCerame].[dbo].[FactureClient]))  
    ,DATEPART(day, (select convert (nvarchar(20),[DateFacture]) FROM [ArcoCerame].[dbo].[FactureClient]))  
    ,DATEPART(dayofyear, (select convert (nvarchar(20),[DateFacture]) FROM [ArcoCerame].[dbo].[FactureClient]))  
    ,DATEPART(weekday, (select convert (nvarchar(20),[DateFacture]) FROM [ArcoCerame].[dbo].[FactureClient]));
```

Error:

> Msg 512, Niveau 16, État 1, Ligne 1
> La sous-requête a retourné plusieurs valeurs. Cela n'est pas autorisé quand la sous-requête suit =, !=, <, <= , >, >= ou quand elle est utilisée en tant qu'expression.

Can you help me guys to correct my statement and thanks in advance

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Note that SO is for question and answers in English.

Comment: [Google is your friend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `year()` and `month()` functions *on the  date*.  Don't convert to strings for date operations!

So, something like this:

```
SELECT year([DateFacture]), month([DateFacture]), day([DateFacture])
FROM [ArcoCerame].[dbo].[FactureClient]
```